# Creating a s3 bucket on clicking register button of a php file

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

i want to create a s3 bucket for my php application that is hosted on ec2, the register.php class contains the code for registering a user on click of button the s3 bucket should be generated for each user. How to do this using python sdk for aws and aws lambda function?

editing the post--
THe task given to me is as follows--
"" The application should have a registration page and user can register on it. (Use AWS RDS as a database)As the user registers there should be a S3 bucket created for the user.Then user can upload the images into his bucket through a different form accessible only after login.
Write a python script which runs using AWS Lambda when the user uploads the images.The Python script should generate some report and store it into another AWS S3 bucket.The user should be able to view the report of his uploads in his login."

My approach to this is that I created an ec2 instance and then installed xampp mysql and phpmyadmin in the ec2.(i decided to transistion to RDS later on)
Then i created the /var/html/www directory in the ubuntu, gave it the permissions to read write.In this directory i will create the php files for login,registration and user's page.
I have doubt over how to create s3 bucket on registration automatically
and how to generate the report using aws lambda on click of the upload image button.

Comment: Why would you use Python SDK if your website uses PHP?

Comment: i want to use aws lambda and use the register button click as a trigger to generate a s3 bucket,can't we use any of the programming languages(Node.js, Python, Java, C#, and Go.) to achieve this.

Comment: For this purpose can i use PHP sdk

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with `mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create an S3 bucket for every user in your application. By default, your AWS service account is limited to 100 buckets.

If you need to support multiple users in your application, store their objects under different prefixes within a single bucket.